# ControlM job calling unix script fails repeatatively

Tags: shell, unix, control-m

I have a controlM job which calls a shell script that takes 4 command line parameters. The command is below:

```
sh /appl/Script/Script1.sh ABC  /appl/Landing SV_SID_NormalisedEvent_* Y
```

The 3rd parameter (`SV_SID_NormalisedEvent_*`) in the command line is a file wildcard/pattern for which the script looks for in the path provided in the second parameter (`/appl/Landing`).

This job was running fine to date when it aborted for one specific corrupt file: `SV_SID_NormalisedEvent_20150810_151805.csv.gz`. We have handled this failure manually by ignoring this file and forced ok job

Since then whenever this job is triggered during daily runs it always fires command as below and fails. Somehow the 3rd parameter is always passed as a specific file rather than the wildcard:

```
sh /appl/Script/Script1.sh ABC /appl/Landing SV_SID_NormalisedEvent_20150810_151805.csv SV_SID_NormalisedEvent_20150810_151805.csv.gz Y
```

The correct command output when the job was running fine is as below:

```
sh /appl/Script/Script1.sh ABC /appl/Landing 'SV_SID_NormalisedEvent*' Y
```

Any pointers to this issue? The above command output is from sysout file created during each run.

Answer (score 0):

> We have handled this failure manually by ignoring this file and forced
>   ok job

It sounds like perhaps the file has not been cleaned up and is being found every time.  Is that possible?

The job will run with the command line that is defined in if this still contains the proper parameter `SV_SID_NormalisedEvent_*`.

I can't think of any other reason you are seeing this behaviour.